Force prevent widget build() in Flutter
Suppose MyWidget is a child widget of MyApp in Flutter. Inside MyWidget, the counter values of two InheritedWidgets are referenced. When you press the count up button placed on MyWidget, the value of each counter will be incremented.
Note that one counter increments one second after pressing the button, and a second counter increments two seconds later. At this time, MyWidget will be rebuilt with each counter updated. This means that every time you press the button, two rebuilds will be performed.
In this case, is there a way to rebuild MyWidget only when both counters are updated after the button is pressed?
As you consider your solution, assume the following constraints:

Assume that the delay time for each counter increment varies each time. The delay times of 1 second and 2 seconds are only provisional values.
Assume that you can only edit MyWidget or add new widgets under MyWidget. You may not be able to edit other widgets, for example because they are part of an external library.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

// -------------------
// Inherited Counter A
// -------------------
class InheritedCounterA extends InheritedWidget {
  const InheritedCounterA({
    super.key,
    required this.data,
    required super.child,
  });

  final CounterStateA data;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedCounterA oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}

class CounterA extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterA({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
  });

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<CounterA> createState() => CounterStateA();

  static CounterStateA of(BuildContext context) {
    final result =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<InheritedCounterA>();
    assert(result != null);
    return result!.data;
  }
}

class CounterStateA extends State<CounterA> {
  int count = 0;

  void increment() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        count++;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InheritedCounterA(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

// -------------------
// Inherited Counter B
// -------------------
class InheritedCounterB extends InheritedWidget {
  const InheritedCounterB({
    super.key,
    required this.data,
    required super.child,
  });

  final CounterStateB data;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedCounterB oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}

class CounterB extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterB({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
  });

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<CounterB> createState() => CounterStateB();

  static CounterStateB of(BuildContext context) {
    final result =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<InheritedCounterB>();
    assert(result != null);
    return result!.data;
  }
}

class CounterStateB extends State<CounterB> {
  int count = 0;

  void increment() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        count++;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InheritedCounterB(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

// ----------
// UI Widgets
// ----------
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: CounterA(
        child: CounterB(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counterA = CounterA.of(context);
    final counterB = CounterB.of(context);

    print("Re-build");
    print("CounterA count: ${counterA.count}");
    print("CounterB count: ${counterB.count}");

    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("CounterA count: ${counterA.count}"),
        Text("CounterB count: ${counterB.count}"),
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            counterA.increment();
            counterB.increment();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

You can force a rebuild by passing a key to the widget and changing it. Therefore, if there is a way to forcibly prevent widget builds, developers will be able to control widget build timing as they wish, and I think it will be a solution to this problem.
Finally, while I understand that deviating from Flutter's standard widget building procedures is not recommended, due to the various constraints I'm facing, I have to take the solution above.
I tried catching the widget as shown below, but of course, the behavior of being rebuilt twice did not change.
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Widget? _cachedWidget;
  (int countA, int countB)? _previousCount;

  Widget _build(BuildContext context) {
    final counterA = CounterA.of(context);
    final counterB = CounterB.of(context);

    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("CounterA count: ${counterA.count}"),
        Text("CounterB count: ${counterB.count}"),
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            counterA.increment();
            counterB.increment();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counterA = CounterA.of(context);
    final counterB = CounterB.of(context);

    _cachedWidget = _cachedWidget == null ||
            _previousCount != (counterA.count, counterB.count)
        ? _build(context)
        : _cachedWidget;

    print("Re-build");
    print("CounterA count: ${counterA.count}");
    print("CounterB count: ${counterB.count}");

    return _cachedWidget!;
  }
}


